# How to write codes to make object can run chaining function for stack- an javascript example in book

Tags: javascript

I meet a problem about how to run the stack function chaining.
I hope to run `stack.push('hello').top()`, but the result is an error message: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined".

```js
 var StackMaker = function() {
   var array = [],
     index = -1;

   return {
     push: function(value) {
       array[index += 1] = value
     },
     pop: function() {
       var value = array[index];
       if (index >= 0) {
         index -= 1
       }
       return value
     },
     top: function() {
       var value = array[index];
       return value;
     },
     isEmpty: function() {
       return index < 0
     }
   }
 };


stack = StackMaker();
stack.push('hello').top(); // "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined"
```

Is that possible to modify, and how to do that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the relevant code directly in the question body. Anyway, without having looked at your fiddle, I think your `.push()` function would need to return the object it is called on (so probably just add `return this`).

Comment: Include code directly into question body and remove jsfiddle link. Correct some grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript, if a function does not return anything (like your push method), it implicitly returns `undefined`. Hence:

```
 push: function(value) {
   array[index += 1] = value
 },
```

is equivalent to

```
 push: function(value) {
   array[index += 1] = value;

   return undefined;
 },
```

That's why you're getting the error saying `undefined` does not have a property called `top`.

The solution is just to explicitly return a reference to the stack itself (`this`):

```js
 var StackMaker = function() {
   var array = [],
     index = -1;

   return {
     push: function(value) {
       array[index += 1] = value;
       
       return this; // <---
     },
     pop: function() {
       var value = array[index];
       if (index >= 0) {
         index -= 1
       }
       return value
     },
     top: function() {
       var value = array[index];
       return value;
     },
     isEmpty: function() {
       return index < 0
     }
   }
 };


 stack = StackMaker();
 console.log(stack.push('hello').top()); // 'hello'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you'll just have to return a reference of the object when you push a new element:

```
push: function(value) {
    array[index += 1] = value;

    return this; // return a reference of this object so we can call other functions on it
},
```

**Example:**

```js
 var StackMaker = function() {
   var array = [],
     index = -1;

   return {
     push: function(value) {
       array[index += 1] = value;
       return this;
     },
     pop: function() {
       var value = array[index];
       if (index >= 0) {
         index -= 1
       }
       return value
     },
     top: function() {
       var value = array[index];
       return value;
     },
     isEmpty: function() {
       return index < 0
     }
   }
 };


 var stack = StackMaker();

 // console.log(stack.push("hello")); will log the object not the last pushed value
 stack.push("JavaScript");
 
 console.log(stack.isEmpty()); //=> false
 console.log(stack.pop()); //=> 'JavaScript'
 console.log(stack.push('hello').top()); //=> 'hello'
 console.log(stack.isEmpty()); //=> true
```

Comment: Beat me to it.. Yeah just return this.

Comment: @John next time.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're trying to simulate how arrays work in JavaScript, you can use the following:

```js
 var StackMaker = function() {
   var stack = [];

   return {
     push: function(value) {
       stack.push(value)
       return value;
     },
     pop: function() {
       return stack.pop();
     },
     top: function() {
       return stack[stack.length - 1];
     },
     isEmpty: function() {
       return stack.length === 0;
     }
   }
 };


 stack = StackMaker();
 console.log(stack.isEmpty());
 //=> true
 console.log(stack.push('hello'));
 //=> 'hello'
 console.log(stack.push('JavaScript'));
 //=> 'JavaScript'
 console.log(stack.isEmpty());
 //=> false
 console.log(stack.pop());
 //=> 'JavaScript'
 console.log(stack.pop());
 //=> 'hello'
 console.log(stack.isEmpty());
 //=> true
```